# Objective C : Can I download a file outside app’s sandbox directory so other Apps can see it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing one application which will download a file and put it outside the app’s sandbox directory, so that other apps can access it. Is it possible? If it is not possible than how does browser downloads files and other apps access the files downloaded by browsers?

Comment: Not possible to access out side app sandbox. I think with browser if you download any zip then it shows options to copy it in any of app like xender (sharing)

Comment: What kind of files you want to save? You can save images to gallery and they can be accessible by all application.

Comment: I am trying to save pdf,docs.ppt,images.

Comment: you have to convert PDF files to image then can save to device's image gallery, this'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604857/convert-pdf-to-uiimage

Answer (score 0):

No. Apps must stay inside their sandbox. Though apps you create can share data between them. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: @AnkitMaurya The browser follows the same rules.